# Ruby math: take a number from a larger number range and calculate where it falls on a smaller range

Tags: ruby, arrays, math, hash, dictionary

Say I have a sorted hash of key => number values, like so:

```
h = { "sebastian" => 0.04, "joshua" => 0.1, "alli" => 0.2, "oliver" = >0.2,  
    ... 
    "wendi" => 1.9, "esther" => 2.1, "mauricio" => 2.6, "fred" => 3.9 }
```

In this hash the min value is 0.04 and the max value is 3.9. (In other hashes this might be completely different, e.g., 3..90, 1.5..900, etc.)

Now I have an ordered array, something like this:

```
a = ["lowest", "lower", "low", "normal", "high", "higher", "highest"]
```

Given any one value in the hash, say 1.9, how do I figure out where this value falls on the range described in the array?

(Please forgive the Ruby and math newbness here!)

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

Apologies for the unclear question. Still trying to figure out how to describe this.

Here is a conceptual example of how I am currently solving my problem that may help.

```
scores = { "sebastian" => 0.04, "joshua" => 0.1, "alli" => 0.2, "oliver" => 0.2, 
           "wendi" => 1.9, "esther" => 2.1, "mauricio" => 2.6, "fred" => 3.9 }
adjectives = ["lowest", "lower", "low", "average", "high", "higher", "higher"]

scores.each_pair do |student, score|
    adj_idx = case score
        when 3.35..4 then 6
        when 2.8..3.34 then 5
        when 2.25..2.7 then 4
        when 1.7..2.24 then 3
        when 1.15..1.6 then 2
        when 0.6..1.16 then 1
        else 0
    end
    puts "#{student} score was in the #{adjectives[adj_idx]}."
end
```

**So my question:** Given a range of student scores that might vary (e.g., scores might be GPAs 0.0..4.0, or test scores 0..110), and a range of "adjectives" that might also vary (e.g., "higher" and "lower" might be removed), is there a way to map scores to adjectives without "manually" building each case like I've done above.

Thanks again!

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks for all your help. I think I've got the following solution working. The key formula is this:

**adj_idx = ( (adjectives.size - 1) * ( (score - min_score).to_f / (max_score - min_score).to_f )  ).round**

```
min_score = scores.values.min
max_score = scores.values.max

scores.each_pair do |student, score|
    adj_idx = ( (adjectives.size - 1) * ((score - min_score).to_f / (max_score - min_score).to_f)  ).round
    puts "#{student} score was in the #{adjectives[adj_idx]} range."
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of "where it falls"?  Do you mean what would its index be if it were inserted into the array?  Sorry I am not following....

Comment: sure thing. ok, what i mean is, how can i calculate if 1.9 is "lowest", "lower", "low", etc. in a number range from .04 to 3.9. and with a solution that is flexible enough to work if 1. the number range is different, e.g., 1.5..300 AND 2. the array of labels is different, e.g., a = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. hope that makes sense.

Comment: How do you define what "lowest", "lower", … "highest" are? Even splits? Do you round if it is between two or take the floor or ceiling?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, i've updated my question. hopefully is clearer now. thanks.

Comment: "is there a way to map scores to adjectives without "manually" building each case like I've done above"  Yes, describe the algorithm you used for building the tresholds manually, then implement it with code. Note that there is no single correct way to do it - do you want the value range to be divided linearly, geometrically, or maybe exponentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value range to be *linearly* divided into equal sized subranges, this should do the trick for you:

```
min = scores.values.min
max = scores.values.max
nsub = adjectives.size
tresholds = (1..nsub).map do |n|
  min + (max - min) * (n / nsub.to_f)
end

scores.each_pair do |student, score|
  adj_index = tresholds.index {|t| t >= score }
  puts "#{student} score was in the #{adjectives[adj_idx]}."
end
```

Comment: fantastic. thank you. yes, linear is what i was looking for. i'm so new to ruby i'll have to study your solution to fully understand. fwiw, it is giving slightly different results than solution i just added to my original question above. given the _scores = { "sebastian" => 0.04, "joshua" => 0.25, "alli" => 0.68, "oliver" => 1.3, "wendi" => 1.9, "esther" => 2.1, "mauricio" => 2.8, "patrick" => 3.15, "fred" => 3.9 }_, mine gives mauricio a "high" score, whereas yours gives him a "higher" score.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array with ranges:

```
a = [["lowest",(0.01..0.09), ["lower",(0.1..0.9)], ...]
```

And then iterate through your hash and assign the literal range:

```
h.each do |key,value|
  literal_range = a.find { |(literal,range)| range.include?(value) }.first
  h[key] = literal_range if literal_range
end
```

The result will be like this:

```
{ "sebastian" => 'lowest', "joshua" => 'lower', ... }
```

The question is not so clear so I made some guess, but I think it will give you something to think about.

Comment: thanks, i think what i'm trying to figure out is if it's possible to calculate how the values in the entire hash (0.04..3.9) would map to the "adjectives" array without manually defining each range myself. does that make sense? i've added more details to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define yourself what is `lowest`, `lower` etc. like

```
rankings = {0.04         => 'lowest',
            (0.05..1.00) => 'lower',
            (1.01..1.50) => 'low',
            (1.51..2.50) => 'normal',
            (2.51..2.90) => 'high',
            (2.91..3.89) => 'higher',
            3.90         => 'highest',
           }
```

Then you can just do:

```
puts rankings.detect { |range, ranking| range === h['joshua'] }.last
#=> lower
```

Comment: thanks, this is similar to how i am currently solving the problem. i'm wondering if there is a way to do this without having to "manually" map my ranges though. i've updated my original question with a (hopefully) clearer example.

Comment: You'll have to map it somehow, there's no magic function that maps ranges to english adjectives ... now, maybe there's a smarter way to do it, like defining a method on the Range class maybe, but still, you have to write the mapping somewhere

Comment: taking the min and max values in the score value range along with adjectives.size, and assuming that 1) adjectives are evenly distributed and that 2) adjectives.first represents the lowest range and adjectives.last represents the highest range, i'm imagining there could write an equation that does map them equally. for example, if the score range is [0..100], and the adjectives are [D,C,B,A] then we could divide 100/4 and "magically" map 0..25 to D, 26..50 to C, 51..75 to B, 76..100 to A. does that make sense?

Comment: @seanomlor If you have an algorithm, why don't you try to write the code ?

Comment: you're right. sorry. i am brand new to ruby and also was struggling with the math. i believe this is the solution:  ((adjectives.size - 1) * ((score - min_score).to_f / (max_score - min_score).to_f) ).round